# Hibernates generates VARBINARY column with JPA @Enumerated annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

Hibernates is generating a VARBINARY column with JPA @Enumerated annotation. I'm using SQL Server 2005 w/ JTDS driver. The mapping is dirt simple:

```
@Basic
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private MyEnum foo;
```

I would have expected Hibernate to generate an integer column? I've also tried EnumType.STRING (expecting a varchar column) with no success.

Note that my app works fine; the column type makes it hard to inspect the DB, and to issue adhoc SQL when poking at the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a stupid user error. Contrary to what I posted in my question, I messed up the "dirt simple" mapping. Instead of declaring my member variable as MyEnum, I instead had this:

```
@Basic
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private Enum foo;
```

Well of course Hibernate had to store binary data, since I told it I wanted to store arbitrary enum values. Changing the type of foo to MyEnum "fixed" the problem.

Comment: If later readers stumble upon this problem but theirs is not about `enum`s: You might try to store your complex type in a simple column. Then you likely want to implement a JPA `AttributeConverter` which converts types like `UserName` to `String` or `PersonAge` to `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Might be an SQL Server specific issue (maybe you could have a look into the Hibernate SQL Server dialect sources to find out the data type used).

In general, it is probably not a good idea to use `EnumType.ORDINAL` mapping, for the same reason it is not a good idea to use the enum ordinals in plain Java code: adding or removing enum values may easily break your code, since it might change the ordinal of an existing enum value. This is discussed in more details in [Effective Java, 2nd Ed](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) Chapter 6, Item 31.

I have also found [further arguments for this from the DB perspective](http://www.aprilandjake.com/content/hibernates-enumerated-annotation-brittle/).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the issue with the version of Hibernate I'm using but my guess is that Hibernate does not recognize your `enum` property as an `@Enumerated` property (`MyEnum` is an `enum`, right?) and treat it like a `Serializable`. 
I know the JPA spec says it's ok to use `@Basic` with enums but you try without?